# jQuery: How to calculate the maximal attribute value of all matched elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="a" x="6"></div>
<div class="a" x="9"></div>
<div class="a" x="2"></div>
...
<div class="a" x="8"></div>
```

How would you find the maximal `x` value of all `.a` elements ?

Assume that all `x` values are positive integers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just loop over them:

```
var maximum = null;

$('.a').each(function() {
  var value = parseFloat($(this).attr('x'));
  maximum = (value > maximum) ? value : maximum;
});
```

Comment: Nicely done, I would have answered almost the same. I would have added a var for parseInt($(this).attr('x')).

Comment: Since you gave my answer a what if - what if the numbers aren't all integers?

Comment: We...er, I mean "they" know where you live.

Comment: Works a treat. Cheers.

Answer (score 10):

I got another version:

```
var numbers = $(".a").map(function(){
    return parseFloat(this.getAttribute('x')) || -Infinity;
}).toArray();

$("#max").html(Math.max.apply(Math, numbers));
```

This uses the map function to extract the values of the x-Attributes, converts the object into an array and provides the array elements as function parameters to `Math.max`

The Math.max trick was stolen from http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/

**UPDATE**

add "|| -Infinity" to process the case correctly, when no attribute is present. See fiddle of @kubedan

Answer (score 2):

Coming back to this with modern javascript:

```
let maxA = $(".a").get().reduce(function (result, item) {
  return Math.max(result, $(item).attr("x"));
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var max = null;

$('.a').each(function() {
  var x = +($(this).attr('x'));
  if (max === null || x > max)
    max = x;
}

alert(max === null ? "No matching elements found" : "The maximum is " + max);
```

Note the unary `+` operator to convert the attribute to a number. You may want to add some error checking to ensure it actually *is* a number - and that the attribute exists at all. You could change the selector to only select elements with the class and the attribute: `$('.a[x]')`.

Comment: What if `max(x)` is less than `0`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var max =0;
$('.a').each(function(){

    if(parseFloat($(this).attr('x'))>max)
    {
         max = parseFloat($(this).attr('x')) ;
    }
});

alert(max);
```

Comment: But this makes `max` a string. Make it an integer or a float.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Array.sort in jQuery, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160498/sort-element-by-numerical-value-of-data-attribute) then use $('.a:last') to get the selected element.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some tests regarding this topic, and if performance matters, a old but gold simple `for` would be better than `jQuery.map()`, `Math.apply()` and also `Array.sort()`:

```
var items = $(".a");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var val = items.eq(i).prop('x');
  if (val > max) max = val;
}
```

Here are the **jsperf** tests: http://jsperf.com/max-value-by-data-attribute. Nothing really drastic, but interesting anyway.