# In jquery, trigger a click on the link with the highest 'rel' attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
<a rel="9">Link 1</a>
<a rel="6">Link 2</a>
<a rel="3">Link 3</a>
<a rel="21">Link 4</a>
```

I want to trigger a click on the link with the highest 'rel' value. What is the most efficient way to write this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question?

[jQuery: How to calculate the maximal attribute value of all matched elements?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524583/jquery-how-to-calculate-the-maximal-attribute-value-of-all-matched-elements

Comment: Be careful using the `rel` attribute, because it's supposed to be used for something completely different to what you're doing with it here

Comment: @Gareth agreed -- using a data attribute like `data-index` would be a better choice here. As a fringe benefit, the `.data()` method will automatically parse the value as an integer.

Comment: By the way: triggering a click on an `a` hyperlink will trigger any JavaScript associated with the `click` event, but will **not** load the hyperlink. This is a security feature, and you have to circumvent it by extracting the `href` attribute. Not sure if this was your intention or not (since your sample code has no `href` attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
var max = 0, index = 0;
$('a[rel]').each(function(i){
   if(parseInt($(this).attr('rel'), 10) > max){
      max = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'), 10);
      index = i;
   }
}).eq(index).trigger('click');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LrAYn/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
var maximum = null;

$('a[rel]').each(function() {
  var value = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));
  maximum = (value > maximum) ? value : maximum;
});

$('a[rel="' + maximum + '"]').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the semi-famous map-array-apply trick:

modified HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-index="3">link 1</a>
<!-- et cetera -->
```

JS:

```
var tarr = $('a').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('index');
}).toArray();
alert( Math.max.apply(Math,tarr) );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/nsBYS/

By the way: triggering a click on an a hyperlink will trigger any JavaScript associated with the click event, but will not load the hyperlink. This is a security feature, and [you have to circumvent it by extracting the href attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4158847/901048). Not sure if this was your intention or not (since your sample code has no href attributes).