# How can I sort elements by numerical value of data attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple elements with the attribute: `data-percentage`, is there a way of sorting the elements into ascending order with the lowest value first using either JavaScript or jQuery?

HTML:

```html
<div class="testWrapper">
  <div class="test" data-percentage="30">
  <div class="test" data-percentage="62">
  <div class="test" data-percentage="11">
  <div class="test" data-percentage="43">
</div>
```

Desired result:

```html
<div class="testWrapper">
  <div class="test" data-percentage="11">
  <div class="test" data-percentage="30">
  <div class="test" data-percentage="43">
  <div class="test" data-percentage="62">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a wrapping div around those divs?

Comment: Yes, there is - I've updated the question to reflect.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
var $wrapper = $('.testWrapper');

$wrapper.find('.test').sort(function(a, b) {
    return +a.dataset.percentage - +b.dataset.percentage;
})
.appendTo($wrapper);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UdvDD/

---

If you're using IE < 10, you can't use the `dataset` property. Use `getAttribute` instead:

```
var $wrapper = $('.testWrapper');

$wrapper.find('.test').sort(function(a, b) {
    return +a.getAttribute('data-percentage') - +b.getAttribute('data-percentage');
})
.appendTo($wrapper);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UdvDD/1/

Comment: You don't *need* the unary plus here, since `-` will convert both operands to numbers. It makes things clearer though.

Comment: @FelixKling - I hate implicit casting. If I'm doing math, I like to be dealing with numbers directly.

Comment: jQuery.data is your friend

Comment: @LukeOliff - Sometimes. In this case it's not needed, so I don't want its overhead.

Comment: @JosephSilber well done, work greate! I have one question if div don't have 'data-percentage' I want to go last place, is this possible ? Thanks.

Comment: @diank - `return (+a.dataset.percentage || 100) - (+b.dataset.percentage || 100)`

Comment: `find` is a jQuery specific method ??

Comment: @oldboy - it is. Nowadays you can use the native `querySelectorAll` method, which is mostly similar to jQuery's `find` method.

Answer (score 11):

```
$('.testWrapper').find('.test').sort(function (a, b) {
   return $(a).attr('data-percentage') - $(b).attr('data-percentage');
})
.appendTo('.testWrapper');
```

Comment: Gilber I have one question if div don't have 'data-percentage' I want to go last place, is this possible ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, on Firefox 64.0.2, none of the answers worked for me. This is what worked in the end, a mixture of Joseph Silber and Jeaf Gilbert's answers:

```
var $wrapper = $('.testWrapper');

$wrapper.find('.test').sort(function(a, b) {
    return +$(a).data('percentage') - +$(b).data('percentage');
})
.appendTo($wrapper);
```

Comment: explanation is that if you set data value like me `.data('percentage',5)` then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538335/jquery-data-attr-not-setting it's being set internally thus nor dataset.percentage nor .getAttribute('data-percentage') work

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Tinysort Jquery plugin should be an option, you can get it i here: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

I did not tried it but the code should look like this:

```
$("#test > div").tsort("",{attr:"data-percentage"});
```

hope this will help

Comment: There's no need for that first empty-string-argument. Just pass it the object as its sole argument.

Answer (score 0):

A more robust option, this function can allow you to sort elements based on multiple options.

https://jsfiddle.net/L3rv3y7a/1/

```
// This calls the function
DOYPSort('#wrapper', '.element', value, order);

    // Parameters must be strings
    // Order of must be either 'H' (Highest) or 'L' (Lowest)
    function DOYPSort(wrapper, elementtosort, AttrToSort, orderof) {
        $(wrapper).find(elementtosort).sort(function (a, b) {
            if (orderof === 'H') {
                return +b.getAttribute(AttrToSort) - +a.getAttribute(AttrToSort);
            } 
            if (orderof === 'L') {
                return +a.getAttribute(AttrToSort) - +b.getAttribute(AttrToSort);
            }
        }).appendTo(wrapper);
    }
```