# How to sort divs by 2 data attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I modify my code so that it sorts by both data-status and then data-order? ie the desired result is 1,2,3,4

I need to support IE.

```js
$(document.body).on('click', "#sortthem", function(){

    var divList = $(".sortme");
    
    divList.sort(function(a, b){
        return $(a).data("status")-$(b).data("status")
    });
    
    $("#mydivs").html(divList);

});
```

```html
<div id="mydivs">
  
    <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="2">4</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="4">3</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="2">2</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="1">1</div>
    

</div>

<span class="btn btn-primary" id="sortthem" >Sort them</span>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Given your HTML the output will be `1,2,4,3`

Comment: Good point, well spotted - thanks

Comment: My js is not strong enough to determine which of the answers is the best so have gone with the first one, which personally I find easier to follow. However if others who know more about js consider one of the other answers superior please let me know as I could update I guess. Thank you all for your answers which are much appreciated.

Comment: They're all valid answers.  Go with the one that you find the most useful / easiest to follow / will use in the future / has the clearest explanation that helps you to apply to your own scenario without just copy+paste.  eg if you need multiple parameters (more than 2) then coding each one each time will become tedious and the .map/.reduce solution will be invaluable, but until then, it might be cleaner to check what you need as you need it.  The best way to show your appreciation for all the answers is to upvote them :)

Comment: You predicted the future @freedomn-m perfectly! I ended up needing > 2 parameters later on and therefore have also made use of the map/.reduce solution. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this for multiple parameters

```js
$(document.body).on('click', "#sortthem", function(){
    var divList = $(".sortme");
    divList.sort(multiSort(["status","order"]));
    $("#mydivs").html(divList);
});
function multiSort(fields) {
    return function (a, b) {
        return fields
            .map(function (o) {
               return $(a).data(o) > $(b).data(o) ?  1 :  $(a).data(o) < $(b).data(o) ? -1 : 0 ;
            }).reduce(function firstNonZeroValue (el,n) { return el ? el : n }, 0);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="mydivs">
    <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="2">4</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="4">3</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="2">2</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="1">1</div>
</div>
<span class="btn btn-primary" id="sortthem" >Sort them</span>
```

Comment: My js is not strong enough to determine which of the answers is the best so have gone with the first one, which personally I find easier to follow. However if others who know more about js consider one of the other answers superior please let me know as I could update I guess. Thank you all for your answers which are much appreciated.

Comment: We are here just to help . So not important who gained point or not. You just take the answer which one help more  for you

Comment: Thank you very much - really appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this @pc_coder - I have posted a follow up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63250512/when-sorting-divs-by-multiple-data-attributes-how-to-specify-asc-desc if you have a moment to help with that I'd be really really grateful - thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can add any additional criteria in to the sort directly by checking if the fist criteria result == 0 - then check the second, etc

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document.body).on('click', "#sortthem", function(){

    var divList = $(".sortme");
    
    divList.sort(function(a, b){
    
        var sort1 = $(a).data("status")-$(b).data("status");
        if (sort1 !== 0) return sort1;
        
        var sort2 = $(a).data("order")-$(b).data("order")
        return sort2;        
    });
    
    $("#mydivs").html(divList);

});
```

```html
<div id="mydivs">
  
    <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="2">4</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="4">3</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="2">2</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="1">1</div>
    

</div>

<span class="btn btn-primary" id="sortthem" >Sort them</span>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: My js is not strong enough to determine which of the answers is the best so have gone with the first one, which personally I find easier to follow. However if others who know more about js consider one of the other answers superior please let me know as I could update I guess. Thank you all for your answers which are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To sort by multiple attributes you simply need to put the secondary sorting logic in place where the two primary attributes match. This can be done in a ternary, as in the following example.

Also note that given your HTML the output will be `1,2,4,3` as the `order` of the `4` element is lower than that of the `3`.

```js
$(document.body).on('click', "#sortthem", function() {
  $(".sortme").sort(function(a, b) {
    let $a = $(a), $b = $(b);
    let aStatus = $a.data('status'), bStatus = $b.data('status');
    let aOrder = $a.data('order'), bOrder = $b.data('order');
        
    return aStatus < bStatus ? -1 : 
      aStatus > bStatus ? 1 : 
      aOrder < bOrder ? -1 :
      aOrder > bOrder ? 1 : 0;
  }).appendTo('#mydivs');
});
```

```html
<div id="mydivs">
  <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="2">4</div>
  <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="4">3</div>
  <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="2">2</div>
  <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="1">1</div>
</div>
<span class="btn btn-primary" id="sortthem">Sort them</span>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: My js is not strong enough to determine which of the answers is the best so have gone with the first one, which personally I find easier to follow. However if others who know more about js consider one of the other answers superior please let me know as I could update I guess. Thank you all for your answers which are much appreciated.