# When sorting divs by multiple data attributes how to specify ASC / DESC?

Tags: javascript, sorting

In this question - [How to sort divs by 2 data attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017909/how-to-sort-divs-by-2-data-attributes) [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62018099/3723310) is working well for me. However I need to be able to specify whether each attribute is ASC or DESC

How would I modify the js to enable this please?

I am thinking something like this:

```
divList.sort(multiSort(["status","ASC","order","DESC"]));
```

But I don't know where to begin with making the JS look at every second item in the array and then adjusting the sort order accordingly.

```js
$(document.body).on('click', "#sortthem", function(){
    var divList = $(".sortme");
    divList.sort(multiSort(["status","order"]));
    $("#mydivs").html(divList);
});
function multiSort(fields) {
    return function (a, b) {
        return fields
            .map(function (o) {
               return $(a).data(o) > $(b).data(o) ?  1 :  $(a).data(o) < $(b).data(o) ? -1 : 0 ;
            }).reduce(function firstNonZeroValue (el,n) { return el ? el : n }, 0);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="mydivs">
    <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="4">4</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="2">3</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="2">2</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="1">1</div>
</div>
<span class="btn btn-primary" id="sortthem" >Sort them</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more semantical (and easier to code) to wrap the fields and directions into subarrays, like:

```
divList.sort(multiSort([["status","ASC"],["order","DESC"]]));
```

If this is OK, then you could easily modify your code:

```js
$(document.body).on('click', "#sortthem", function(){
    var divList = $(".sortme");
    divList.sort(multiSort([["status","ASC"],["order","DESC"]]));
    $("#mydivs").html(divList);
});
function multiSort(fields) {
    return function (a, b) {
        return fields
            .map(function ([o, d]) {
               return ($(a).data(o) > $(b).data(o) ?  1 :  $(a).data(o) < $(b).data(o) ? -1 : 0) * (d === 'ASC' ? 1 : d === 'DESC' ? -1 : 0);
            })
            .reduce(function firstNonZeroValue (el,n) { return el ? el : n }, 0);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="mydivs">
    <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="4">4</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="2">3</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="2">2</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="1">1</div>
</div>
<span class="btn btn-primary" id="sortthem" >Sort them</span>
```

Or, an ES5 version:

```js
$(document.body).on('click', "#sortthem", function(){
    var divList = $(".sortme");
    divList.sort(multiSort([["status","ASC"],["order","DESC"]]));
    $("#mydivs").html(divList);
});
function multiSort(fields) {
    return function (a, b) {
        return fields
            .map(function (o) {
               return ($(a).data(o[0]) > $(b).data(o[0]) ?  1 :  $(a).data(o[0]) < $(b).data(o[0]) ? -1 : 0) * (o[1] === 'ASC' ? 1 : o[1] === 'DESC' ? -1 : 0);
            })
            .reduce(function firstNonZeroValue (el,n) { return el ? el : n }, 0);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="mydivs">
    <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="4">4</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="2" data-order="2">3</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="2">2</div>
    <div class="sortme" data-status="1" data-order="1">1</div>
</div>
<span class="btn btn-primary" id="sortthem" >Sort them</span>
```

Comment: That absolutely is OK and works like a charm - including with > 2 fields. Thank you very much for your help, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Ah - I'm getting an error in IE 11 "Expected identifier" in the .map function - I don't suppose you have any ideas as to how I need to modify the code to make it work in IE do you please? Thank you so much if so!

Comment: @happysailingdude It's because IE11 doesn't support destructuring. If you need to support it, replace `([o, d])` with `(o)` and replace every occurrences of `o` with `o[0]` and `d` with `o[1]` inside that function. I've included it in my answer, take a look