# jQuery data attr not setting

Tags: javascript, jquery

This appears very simple but I cannot see why it's not working. The selector is correct however the div `.faqContent` is simply not being updated with the `data-height` attribute.

```
$('.faqItem .faqContent').each(function(){
    var h = $(this).height();
    $(this).data('height',h);
});
```

I have checked that   `var h` is correct, it is in colsole.log as correctly holding the height.

**EDIT**
It's absolutely not conflict, and console shows no errors.

Comment: FYI value being set by the .data() will not be reflected while you inspecting those elements.

Comment: try to console the value. so you will get the value for each.

Comment: if data-height attritbute already exists and you trying to update it then it wont work...you need to use `.attr(data-height,h)`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You will not be able to see it in the element inspector but *it is there* as jquery set the data attribute internally.

try `console.log($(this).data('height'));`

Comment: Absolutely spot on. Thanks @Mohammad Adil, it is there.

Comment: How confusing! Terrible design. Thank you though :)

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu It's specifically designed this way to save in cache for speed as it is wasteful to re-evaluate on every `.data()` call

Comment: @JackNicholson the design is good, it's just the name that confuses me (and apparently many other people).

Comment: Yes, it's the for jQuery. But it's not there if you want to use a CSS selector on it, eg `.myclass[height="0"] { display: none; }` So in this case you should use `$('.myclass').attr('data-height', <value>)`

Answer (score 110):

The `data` function confuses a lot of people, it's not just you. :-)

`data` manages jQuery's internal data object for the element, **not** `data-*` attributes. `data` only uses `data-*` attributes to set *initial values*, and more, it guesses at what type you want those to be based on what they look like (so something that looks like a number is converted to a number; something that looks like JSON gets converted to an object). The `data` method never *sets* `data-*` attributes on elements, it only sets the data on its internal data object. That means the two (the internal data object and the attribute) get out of sync:

```js
const t = $("#target");
let value;

// Getting the attribute always gets a string
value = t.attr("data-height");
console.log(`${value} (${typeof value})`);  // 1 (string)

// Using `.data`, jQuery will guess that because the attribute looks like a number,
// you want it converted to a number
value = t.data("height");
console.log(`${value} (${typeof value})`);  // 1 (number)

// `data` only sets the internal data object properties, not the attribute...
t.data("height", 2);

// ...so the attribute still has `"1"`
value = t.attr("data-height");
console.log(`${value} (${typeof value})`);  // 1 (string)

// ...even though the data object has 2
value = t.data("height");
console.log(`${value} (${typeof value})`);  // 2 (number)
```

```html
<div id="target" data-height="1"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to actually set a `data-*` attribute, use `attr`:

```
$(this).attr("data-height", h);
```

```js
const t = $("#target");
let value;

value = t.attr("data-height");
console.log(`${value} (${typeof value})`);  // 1 (string)

// `attr` converts whatever you give it to string
t.attr("data-height", 2);

value = t.attr("data-height");
console.log(`${value} (${typeof value})`);  // 2 (string)
```

```html
<div id="target" data-height="1"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But if you only want this information for future use, `data` is fine (assuming you're okay with its automatic type conversion), just don't expect to see it in the DOM inspector, because jQuery doesn't write this information to the DOM.

Comment: great answer, solved the mystery of data-attribute. Hats off!

Answer (score 3):

`.data()` is only stores the associated new value in memory(or *internally*). It'll not change the attribute in the DOM hence you cannot see it updated using inspector tools.

To change the attribute, you can use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)**:

```
$('.faqItem .faqContent').each(function(){
    var h = $(this).height();
    $(this).attr('data-height',h);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery .data() stores the value on the element itself, it won't add an attribute.

http://api.jquery.com/data/

If you want to add an attribute, use attr:

```
$('.faqItem .faqContent').each(function(){
    var h = $(this).height();
    $(this).attr('data-height', h);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/