# Dynamically created Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I already found some questions here regarding this topic, but none of them solved my issue. I *do* can create the dropdown, and it even drops down. It just doesn't go away if I click the button again or click outside of it. So I think some events aren't wired correctly, but I can't figure out which.

This is a reduced version of my JS code, it just needs a container `<div>` with the ID `outer`.

```
var container = $('<div>').addClass('dropdown').appendTo($('#outer'));

// simulate test entry
var entry = {
  id: 1
};

var id = 'btn-action-' + entry.id;

$('<button>')
  .addClass('btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle')
  .data('toggle', 'dropdown')
  .attr({
    'type': 'button',
    'id': id,
    'aria-haspopup': 'true',
    'aria-expanded': 'false'
  })
  .text('Actions')
  .appendTo(container);

var listContainer = $('<div>').addClass('dropdown-menu').attr('aria-labelledby', id).appendTo(container);

var actionName = 'Delete';
$('<a>')
  .addClass('dropdown-item')
  .attr('href', '#')
  .click({ 'action': actionName.toLowerCase(), 'entry': entry }, function (e) {
    alert('Invoking ' + e.data.action + ' for entry ' + e.data.entry.id);
    e.preventDefault();
  })
  .text(actionName)
  .appendTo(listContainer);

// this is only necessary because of dynamic creation:
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

Here is a [fiddle showing my issue](https://jsfiddle.net/rnLs3fdp/5/).

Comment: As far as I can see the data attribute `data-toggle` is not set. But right now I have no clue, why your assignment is not working. EDIT: According to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538335/jquery-data-attr-not-setting) I might be wrong. EDIT 2: I am not (totally) wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to "[jQuery data attr not setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538335/jquery-data-attr-not-setting)" `.data(key, value)` only sets the data value internally, but not on the element.

Bootstrap is trying to find all elements `$("[data-toggle='dropdown']")` and cannot find your element. To fix the issue, just add `'data-toggle': 'dropdown'` to your attribute list:

```
$('<button>')
  .addClass('btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle')
  .attr({
    'type': 'button',
    'id': id,
    'data-toggle': 'dropdown',
    'aria-haspopup': 'true',
    'aria-expanded': 'false'
  })
  .text('Actions')
  .appendTo(container);
```

Comment: Thank you! Fun fact: using this solution I don't even need the last line `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();` anymore. :-)