# How to pass JQuery instance in a Handlebars template context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I would like to use Handlebars to insert nested elements which could be jQuery elements such as:

```js
var ul = Handlebars.compile($('#ul').html());
var li = Handlebars.compile($('#li').html());

let el = $(li({slot: 'Hello World!'})).data('foo', Object([42]))

$('#main').append(ul({slot: el}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.1.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<div id="main" class="container">
</div>

<script id="ul" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul>
        {{{slot}}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script id="li" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li>
        {{slot}}
    </li>
</script>
```

Unfortunately I am struggling with two issues:

- Handlebars expect a html content in the context, therefore I loose `data-foo`.
- Using `{{{slot}}}` might be unsafe

What would be the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to this problem is write a wrapper that look for `jQuery` instances in the template `context`. It replaces every instances with a plain text unique identifier then insert back the jQuery instances to the rendered template:

```
Handlebars.jQueryCompile = (template) => {
    let jQueryObjects = []

    let tag = id => `jQueryObject(${id})`

    let alter = (obj) => {
        if (!(obj instanceof Object)) return

        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj[prop] instanceof jQuery) {
                jQueryObjects.push(obj[prop])
                obj[prop] = tag(jQueryObjects.length - 1)
            } else {
                alter(obj[prop])
            }
        }
    }

    return (context) => {
        alter(context)
        let obj = $(template(context))
        jQueryObjects.forEach((jq, id) => {
            obj.find('*:contains("' + tag(id) + '")').html('').append(jq)
        })

        return obj
    }
}
```

Here your updated example:

```
var ul = Handlebars.jQueryCompile($('#ul').html());
var li = Handlebars.jQueryCompile($('#li').html());

let el = $(li({slot: 'Hello World!'})).data('foo', Object([42]))

$('#main').append(ul({slot: el}))
```

Notice that you don't need to use the `{{{}}}` mustaches because plain text is inserted instead of html elements.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option using

1. Use **attr** instead of **data()**, as it only stores value and it will not set attribute on DOM

refer this link for more details - [jQuery data attr not setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538335/jquery-data-attr-not-setting)

2. Split appending ul and el

Code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/PvrLba?editors=1010

```js
var ul = Handlebars.compile($('#ul').html());
var li = Handlebars.compile($('#li').html());

let el = $(li({slot: 'Hello World!'})).attr('data-foo', Object([42]))
$('#main').append(ul)
$('#main ul').append(el)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.1.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<div id="main" class="container">
</div>

<script id="ul" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul>
        {{{slot}}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script id="li" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li>
        {{slot}}
    </li>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you are not solving the main question which is: how to pass a jQuery element in a template context.