# Jquery sort data in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have written the following code which is working when there is alphabetic data, how can I make it work uniquely irrespective of alphabets or numbers

```js
function sortList(selectId) {
  var options = $(selectId + ' option');
  var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
    return {
      t: $(o).text(),
      v: o.value
    };
  }).get();
  arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
  });
  options.each(function(i, o) {
    o.value = arr[i].v;
    $(o).text(arr[i].t);
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  sortList("#whatever");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='whatever'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='10'>10</option>
</select>
```

It is getting sorted as `1,10,2` where I am looking it like `1,2,10`. How to make this function unique to work for all scenarios

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence form. Don't tack on tags. See [ask].

Comment: Just convert them to numbers?

Comment: `arr.sort(function(o1, o2) { if (isNaN(o1.t) && isNaN(o2.t)) return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0; return o1-o2; });
`

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [How can I sort elements by numerical value of data attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160498/how-can-i-sort-elements-by-numerical-value-of-data-attribute)
Here's a snippet with the answer modified from that question to match this question

```js
var element = $("#whatever");
element.find("option").sort(function(a, b) {
    return +a.getAttribute('value') - +b.getAttribute('value');
}).appendTo(element);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='whatever'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
    <option value='9'>9</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='10'>10</option>
</select>
```

I just copied my snipped to your jsfiddle and it worked
Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/g3cjbzey/

Comment: Hi can you look here and correct https://jsfiddle.net/DorababuMeka/u2tj9z7n/

Comment: If I add `<option value="156">0</option>` after `<option value="107">12</option>` it didn't worked

Comment: Yes because it reads the value, not the text inside of it. You can change `a.getAttribute('value')` to `Number(a.textContent)`. Same goes for b